# Can I transmit in the ISM band without a ham radio license?

Tags: transmitter, sdr

I recently purchased a HackRf SDR, which has transmit and recieve capability. I'm debugging a 2.4ghz wireless module, and being able to transmit to it using the hackrf would be very helpful. Since this is in the ISM ("unlicensed?") band, can I transmit *legally* (with a very low power, a few milliwatts) for testing purposes without an amateur radio license? I'm in Canada, by the way.

Comment: there is a Ham radio stack exchange, these people can help you for sure! http://ham.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, thanks, @Bruce. I'll be sure to check that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is totally legal Worldwide, no license needed.
Do you own/use a:

- WiFi access point
- WiFi on a phone or laptop
- Microwave oven
- Bluetooth on a phone or laptop

These all operate in the 2.4 - 2.5 GHz ISM band which is legal as long as the device
transmits less than (I think, correct me if I'm wrong please) 20 dBm = 10 mW

So in your case: no worries, perfectly legal ! Enjoy :-)

Comment: The actual power levels vary from country to country (30dBm in the US, 20dBm in EU). Other ISM bands have different regulations per region.

Comment: And the band's are different sizes. Japan allows 13 channels in the Wifi b/g while US only allows 11.

Comment: And the rules might only allow for FHSS or DSSS. If you're not using spread spectrum, then it should be low duty-cycle or very low power. Effective Radiated Power is also restricted. (20 dBm = 100 mW, legal in most places, only on a low gain antenna...)

Comment: how about other ISM Bands?